# Which X.509 certificate to use for NodeMCU SSL connections?

Tags: azure, openssl, certificate, x509, nodemcu

Wow, SSL authentication is overwhelming!

I am using a NodeMCU device (ESP8266) device to connect to a Microsoft Azure IoT Hub securely using the MQTT protocol.

Microsoft offer the ability to authorise clients using self-signed X.509 certificates.

This is explained in detail here: [Using X.509 Certificates with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started)

I have followed the example that Microsoft Azure give, using OpenSSL to generate my self-signed X.509 certificates.

I try the example Python script to test the connection as a client, using my new certs and **this works very well**. So I know that the process has been a success, as it is tested and working and I am able to publish and subscribe to my IoT Hub.

In order to get the NodeMCU device connecting as a client to the IoT Hub, I need to load a certificate for authentication. NodeMCU provides the facility to load **a single** CA Certificate (in PEM format) into the operating system.

This is documented here: [NodeMCU TLS Documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/tls/#tlscertverify)

**The question is, which certificate should I use?**

I have tried a handful of combinations from the OpenSSL output, but none appear to result in a successful handshake. I am poking and hoping at this stage and could do with some input from someone who knows their stuff.

The encouraging news is that NodeMCU recognises the certificates as X.509 certs but fails on the verification. So this leads me to believe that I have the incorrect cert loaded...

> **-0x2700 MBEDTLS_ERR_X509_CERT_VERIFY_FAILED**
>
> Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RSA Client Side Certificate & Private Key on NodeMCU end to authenticate client using X.509 authentication.

You can place PEM formatted certificate and private key in NodeMCU flash and load them in SRAM. It is a good idea to enclose the certificate and private key in "EOF(" ")EOF" tags.

Hopefully you are using Arduino core for ESP8266, you can them make use of BearSSL to format certificate files for transport layer and associate with WiFiClientSecure object as follows:

```
BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure espClient;

BearSSL::X509List serverCertList(getCertificate());
BearSSL::PrivateKey serverPrivKey(getPrivateKey());
espClient.setClientRSACert(&serverCertList, &serverPrivKey);
```

where, getCertificate() & getPrivateKey() methods you should define to read certificate from flash (or pass character array containing PEM formatted Certificate and Private Key here instead). After this, you will be able to authenticate the client with the server if your certificate and private key belongs to valid chain.